# Adding a group inside of a group in a "Grid" application for the Windows 8 Store

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've got an application I'm developing that displays information about the various function headers in the C99 Standard Library. As you can imagine, some of these headers contain quite a few functions... more than I care to put on the main screen. I think a better way of handling it would be to create groups for each header ( has a summary ITEM then a functions GROUP that contains function ITEMS inside), so they're on their own page.

However, I'm having trouble doing this programmatically with the Microsoft-provided template.

Here's the code I have for the group "complex.h", which would ideally contain a summary item and then a group named "ComplexConstituents":

```
var complexGroup = new SampleDataGroup("<complex.h>",
                "<complex.h>",
                "complex arithmetic",
                "Assets/LightGray.png",
                "Group Description: ");
        complexGroup.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-2-Item-1",
                "Summary",
                "summary of <complex.h>",
                "Assets/DarkGray.png",
                "Item Description: summary of <complex.h>",
                ITEM_CONTENT,
                complexGroup));
        this.AllGroups.Add(complexGroup);
        var complexConstituents = new SampleDataGroup("<complex.h> functions",
                "<complex.h> functions",
                "functions included in the <complex.h> header",
                "Assets/MediumGray.png",
                "Group description: blah");
        this.ComplexConstituents.Add(complexConstituents);
```

You may have noticed that I've added a second type of group to supplement "AllGroups" here. It's "ComplexConstituents", and is supposed to be a group inside  that contains the constituent functions of . Here's the constructor for it, with the constructor for "AllGroups" for comparison:

```
    private ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> _allGroups = new ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup>();
    public ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> AllGroups
    {
        get { return this._allGroups; }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> _complexConstituents = new ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup>();
    public ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> ComplexConstituents
    {
        get { return this._complexConstituents; }
    }
```

I would think this is enough, but for whatever reason, it is not. I get the error at the end of this post (pictured). What do I need to do to fix this?

[image]

EDIT:

Here's the GetItem method requested by some:

```
public static SampleDataItem GetItem(string uniqueId)
    {
        // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
        var matches = _sampleDataSource.AllGroups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: show GetItem method, probably parsing is wrong.

Comment: Edited to include it, chief.

Comment: I post answer. Let me know about success of this change.

Answer (score 0):

In your GetItem method you must make changes becouse you use **ComplexConstituents** as data source.

Edit like this:

```
var matches = _sampleDataSource.ComplexConstituents.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));

 var matches2 = _sampleDataSource.AllGroups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));

        if (matches.Count() == 1) 
            return matches.First();
        else if(matches2.Count() == 1)
            return matches2.First();
        else
           return null;
```

Comment: It would seem as if this presents another problem. The other "main" groups on the home page of the application require var matches to deal with AllGroups, not ComplexConstituents. Would it be possible to create a case for each group?

Comment: I edited my post. But in this case you need to have diffrend items in groups. Other way is to implement second method.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to alleviate the problem. When clicking on the other items on the page, it doesn't bring anything up, and just stays on the home page. The group doesn't show up under the other items in the complex.h category, either. :/